# Async design pattern - which one is better?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, .net-4.5

I've started wondering for asynchronous programming should I always use following pattern:

```
public async Task<int> MyMethodAsync()
{
    return await SomeOtherMethodAsync();
}
```

or is it safe and do not produce any drawback, simplify this code to:

```
public Task<int> MyMethodAsync()
{
    return SomeOtherMethodAsync();
}
```

I've started reading over internet, and cannot find any answer, all async programming is mention only first pattern.

**UPDATE 1**

Based on some answer, in trivial method, second is proper one. But if I extend and write method in following way - this is still in relation to above code, just to show what inside `SomeOtherMethodAsync` method:

```
public async Task<int> SomeOtherMethodAsync()
{
    var result1 = await LongRunningThirdMethod();
    var result2 = await LongRunningForthMethod();

    return result1 + result2;
}
```

and modify my second example to:

```
public Task<int> MyMethodAsync()
{
    SomeSyncMethod();
    SomeOtherSyncCode();

    return SomeOtherMethodAsync();
}
```

Comment: As an aside, `SomeOtherMethodAsync` unnecessarily awaits `LongRunningThirdMethod` before starting `LongRunningFourthMethod` - instantiate both tasks and *then* await them so they can run concurrently.

Comment: Thanks, it was just simple example, what is inside, to expand primary question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In that specific case, there is no need for the await overhead.

async/await is meant to make the previous callback hell, feel more like synchronous programming.
And since you don't have anything to do after the Async call, there is really no need to use await in this case.

So you are right to just return the async method, and it even still holds its promise.

**Update 1**

Both of those cases are correct. When you do await/async, the compiler creates a state machine behind the scene to handle all the callbacks for you, and there is no need to create one, if you aren't using it. So both examples, are proper async/await code.

You could optimize it though, by waiting for both tasks simultaneously.

```
public async Task<int> SomeOtherMethodAsync()
{
    var resultTask1 = LongRunningThirdMethod();
    var resultTask2 = LongRunningForthMethod();

    await Task.WhenAll(resultTask1, resultTask2);

    return resultTask1.Result + resultTask2.Result;
}
```

or even:

```
public async Task<int> SomeOtherMethodAsync()
{
    var resultTask1 = LongRunningThirdMethod();
    var resultTask2 = LongRunningForthMethod();

    return await resultTask1 + await resultTask2;
}
```

See Yuval Itzchakov answer for another alternative.
The point is, here you start both, and then await them afterwards. Where in your example you start one, wait for it to complete, then starts the next... etc.

Comment: Worth noting that this only applies in the trivial case in question - if that is supposed to represent a general example then it may not be so simple.

Comment: @AntP Correct, and I agree. But if we look at a method, with only a single call to an async method, with no need to call something afterwards that uses the return of that async call, you can just return the 'handle' to the caller, and let it handle it.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you're trying to do.
Usually, when you only make one asynchronous call inside your method and that is all, you can save yourself the state-machine overhead and simply return the `Task`, which will be awaited higher up the call stack.

Your second example (of update 1) has to wait for both results of the asynchronous operation to return. What you can do is modify your code so both operations run concurrently using `Task.WhenAll`:

```
public async Task<int> SomeOtherMethodAsync()
{
    int[] results = await Task.WhenAll(LongRunningThirdMethod(), LongRunningForthMethod());
    return results.Sum();
}
```

This way, you aren't sequentially waiting for each operation to complete. Once they both return, you compute the sum.

Comment: The concurrency example is subtle and golden. Loved the use of `Sum()`.

Comment: Thanks, I agree that update1 _SomeOtherMethodAsync_ method could be written better, as your example. But in fact it was only extension what is inside that method. Is that change understanding and implementation pattern1 vs pattern2

Comment: `await` cannot be avoided inside pattern 1 since you have two async operations that need to finish because the return value depends on them. In pattern 2, you can propagate the `Task` upwards, and leave it up to the caller to handle it using `await`.